# How to split a Hash and pass it as two separate arguments in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
url = 'SomeUrl'
args{ someKey: 'Value',
      key2: 'Value2'
```

}

The method currently uses both of these as arguments. I combined both these arguments into a single hash as:

```
opts = {
                 Hello: {
                   Name: 'John',
                   Version: '1.0'

                 },
                 World: {
                   platformVersion: '3.4x',
                   helloVersion: '2.3'
                 }
               }
```

What I'm trying is Combine these two hashes and separate them at runtime in this method:

```
   def initialize(opts)
         #this is how it was done before
          SomeClass.for(:remote, opts)
         #What I want here is to split that hash into two arguments
    end
```

Comment: The method uses both? Which method? Combine and separate? You'll have to provide a lot more details.

Comment: Does this help ? Sorry for the earlier edit

Comment: It'll be helpful to provide sample inputs and desired outputs. I couldn't understand what you are trying to achieve here or what the problem is.

Comment: Still don't understand what "split that hash into two arguments" means. How do you want to split? Keys? Values? Pairs? Two separate hashes? There is nothing stopping you from simply using two hash arguments to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
opts = {
  Hello: {
    Name: 'John',
    Version: '1.0'
  },
  World: {
    platformVersion: '3.4x',
    helloVersion: '2.3'
  }
}

def initialize(opts)
      SomeClass.for(:remote, opts[:Hello], opts[:World])
end
```

This is what you want?
`SomeClass.for` method will receive three arguments:

1. `:remote`
2. `{ Name: 'John', Version: '1.0' }`
3. `{ platformVersion: '3.4x', helloVersion: '2.3' }`